# Next.js hostname not configured under images in next.config.js even though remotePatterns was set

Tags: next.js

Next.JS 13.3.1 doesn't seem to pick up the following part of my `next.config.js` file:

```
images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/mycompany-data-bucket-dev/**",
      },
    ],
  },
```

I get the following error, which surprisingly mentions the same protocol and hostname as in my config:

```
Error: Invalid src prop (https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mycompany-data-bucket-dev/media/images/default-female/default-female-500-500.jpg) on `next/image`, hostname "s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host
```

I restarted my local development server and double-checked the error message. My app is running locally on `localhost:3000`.

How can I investigate this problem further? For example is it possible to print my Next.JS config at run-time before the error is raised?

Comment: I had forgotten to specify which format are accepted. I added this to the `images` config, but the problem persists: `formats: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/svg+xml", "image/webp"]`

Answer (score 2):

assuming thats its too late now, but I had a similar issue with images in NextJS 13.4.2.
Images links in my case are like 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/assets/1fad3d7c-d5bd.jpeg', and it was resolved by such next.config.js config:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // ...
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [{
      protocol: 'https',
      hostname: 's3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
      port: '',
      pathname: '/assets/**'
    }]
  },
  // ...
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: works for me in version NextJS 14.0.2

Answer (score 1):

In future if anyone have the same issue, I resolve this issue by using the `format` in images object. As @Giorgio mentioned, in the comment:

> I had forgotten to specify which format are accepted. I added this to the images config, but the problem persists: formats: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/svg+xml", "image/webp"]

First I have tried all these formats as mentioned in the comment `formats: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/svg+xml", "image/webp"]` but still arising the error. Then I just tried these two formats only because typescript also suggest me that two only and it works for me: `formats: ["image/avif", "image/webp"]`

Below is the complete code:

```
images: {
    formats: ["image/avif", "image/webp"],
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/mycompany-data-bucket-dev/**",
      },
    ],
  }
```